# How do I evaluate a sample in a weighted Gaussian Mixture Model?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, gaussian, montecarlo, mixture-model

**Short version:**

If I have a MoG model with n components each with individual weights w^n. 
I have a sample s. I wish to calculate the probability that this sample was drawn from the MoG. I can evaluate the individual gaussians easily but I don't know how to take their weights into account or aggregate their scores.

**Longer Version:**

I am using a MoG model in matlab for a machine learning algorithm. I am sampling   Monte Carlo style and thus need to perform importance re-weighting which involves evaluating the likelihood of drawing a specific sample from the MoG model. I can easily evaluate a single Gaussian but I'm unsure how to go about it for the entire MoG model, taking into account all the components and weights.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the *mathematical* answer would be:

```
y = p(x | M) = \sum_i p(x | N_i) * w_i
```

where `p(x | M)` is the probability of `x` being sampled form the mixture `M`, which is translated to the weighted sum of the probability of `x` being sampled from each of the gaussians `N_i` weighted by the prior probability of sampling from the normal `N_i` (`w_i`, a weight obtained during training).

Find here a detailed document on how to train or sample from a GMM:

http://guneykayim-msc.googlecode.com/svn-history/r20/trunk/doc/common/GMM.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I assumed this would work but couldn't find any resources to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a mathematical answer but Matlab provides the pdf evaluations using the 'pdf' method.

y = pdf(obj,X)

where obj is the gmdistribution object.